# HttpHandlers fire for some paths but not all

Tags: c#, iis, httphandler

I am trying to figure out why certain paths work and others do not for the same httphandler. I am on IIS10.

My handler looks like this:

```
<add name="IconStore" preCondition="integratedMode" path="icons/*" verb="*" type="SomePath.Controls.IconStoreHandler, SomePath.Controls"/>
```

And this handler will fire for this path:

```
<img class="tip" data-tip="redacted" src="icons/interface-question-mark">
```

Which gets added here:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="tip" data-tip="<%$ Resources:Resources, Redacted%>" ImageUrl="icons/interface-question-mark" />
```

but will not fire for this implementation:

```
<div class="redacted" initialized="true" title="" style="background-image: url("icons/interface-question-mark");"></div>
```

Something to note, when I copy the element that is not working from chrome's inspector, the double quotes are `&quot;` but I did some research and doesn't seem to be an issue.

Why does the first implementation fire, but the second one does not? If I use a different handler path, like:

```
      <add name="Icon.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Icon.axd" verb="GET" type="SomePath.Controls.IconStoreHandler, SomePath.Controls"/>
```

And then my implementation is something like:

```
<div class="redacted" initialized="true" title="" style="background-image: url("Icon.axd?name=test");"></div>
```

The handler will fire for both implementations.

Comment: Can you add the generated urls that are getting sent to the browser?  I suspect this is a relative path issue, given how you are structuring your urls "icons/interface-question-mark" vs. "/icons/interface-question-mark"

Comment: @raterus The generated URLs just look like https://localhost/platformicons/name
or 
https://localhost/admin/page/platformicons/name

And the one with the admin/page works, but not the first one.

Comment: I've just tried changing another image url that gets set in CSS, and that doesn't work either. Is there something weird with CSS urls? They don't seem to be triggering my handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the above does work, and I had a re-write rule set up that was redirecting those requests to 
   http://localhost:80/redacted/user?site=icons

I added an Anti-re-write path for icons and it now works.

E: Anti-rewrite path looks like:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^/[\w-]+/icons/*" negate="true" />
```

in rewriteRules.config

Answer (score 1):

I prefer running URLs generation against the server, and let asp.net determine what path to use.  To do this you can use the tilde (~) to represent the root of the application path.

e.g. you would change

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/interface-question-mark" />
```

to

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/interface-question-mark" />
```

~ here is your root application in IIS, so if you are running locally using the tilde is equilivant to typing this in front of the url

```
http://localhost/myappname
```

The resulting url from the first example would be equilivant to

```
http://localhost/myappname/icons/interface-question-mark
```

For your css links (or anything else that isn't a webcontrol, you can do this:

```
<div class="redacted" style="background-image: url('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/icons/interface-question-mark")');"></div>
```

Comment: And what would I do in a CSS file? Just do

    background-image: url("~/icons/icon");

?

Comment: @Kato, look at the bottom of my answer, I had a strategy for CSS as well.  I'm assuming you are using webforms as well, thls would be different in MVC

Comment: but I can't translate that in an actual stylesheet, can I? Do stylesheets not follow the handlers? When I was using my path as Icon.axd?iconName=test that path worked in a style sheet.